# D3 v4 pie chart default text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am quite new in the world of D3. Now I would like to create a pie chart based on this 
[example](https://codepen.io/zakariachowdhury/pen/EZeGJy) with the exception that the first item in the list would be as a default value on the text displayed in the center. I have tried to chain the functions in different places of the code, but haven't been able to find the correct way to do it.

Thank you in advance!

Code also pasted here:

```
    var data = [
{name: "USA", value: 40},
  {name: "UK", value: 20},
  {name: "Canada", value: 30},
  {name: "Maxico", value: 10},
];
var text = "";

var width = 260;
var height = 260;
var thickness = 40;
var duration = 750;

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'pie')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height);

var g = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2) + ',' + (height/2) + ')');

var arc = d3.arc()
.innerRadius(radius - thickness)
.outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d) { return d.value; })
.sort(null);

var path = g.selectAll('path')
.data(pie(data))
.enter()
.append("g")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
      let g = d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "text-group");

      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "name-text")
        .text(`${d.data.name}`)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '-1.2em');

      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "value-text")
        .text(`${d.data.value}`)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '.6em');
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current))
        .select(".text-group").remove();
    })
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current));
    })
  .each(function(d, i) { this._current = i; });


g.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .text(text);
```

Comment: Make a working snippet of your code. That would be faster and easy to debug.

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzRMMV

Comment: Gunner got it right. Thanks! Could be helpful to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a default value to show up, just append the values during rendering of the chart. To update the value `mouseover`, just select the `.text-group` and update the values.

Check updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzRMMV)